# Не работает форма отправки сообщения с сайта без method и action (ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

```
<form id="form" class="form" name="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <h4>Подписаться на новости</h4>
    <label class="form-control-label" for="formGroupExampleInput">Введите ваше имя</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваше имя">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Введите вашу почту</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Электронная почта">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Вводите электронный адрес в формате support@gmail.com</small> 
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="я дaю согласие на обработку моих персональных данных">
        Согласен с условиям политики конфиденциальности
    </label>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primaryFoot btn_bottom">Отправить</button>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#form').submit(function() { // проверка на пустоту заполненных полей. Атрибут html5 — required не подходит (не поддерживается Safari)
    if (document.form.name.value == '' || document.form.phone.value == '' ) {
        valid = false;
        return valid;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/send.php",
        data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        $('.js-overlay-thank-you').fadeIn();
        $(this).find('input').val('');
        $('#form').trigger('reset');
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

При нажатии на «отправить» в адресной строке кидается ссылка http://site.ru/?name=site_admin&email=aap92%40list.ru и данные не отправляются.

При добавлении `action` и `method` код отрабатывает, тем не менее с таким же js кодом вот эта форма работает и без `method` и `action`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-field" name="name" placeholder="Введите ваше имя" /><br />
    <input type="text" class="form-field" name="phone" placeholder="Введите ваш телефон" /><br />
    <button class="btn btn-default form-button"><span class="text-button">Отправить заявку</span></button>
```

Хочу добиться того же, но в чем проблема не могу понять.

Comment: ну второе приведенное - не форма вообще, и не имеет субмита. (ну или Вы вкинули не весь кусок кода). Уберите субмит с формы где Вам нужна ajax отработка и отлавливайте клик, как вариант.

Comment: `$(this).find('input').val('');` - это что делает?